# Using IdentityServer to call API on behalf of a Client not User?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am thinking of using `IdentityServer4` for a new project.  I am new to this and have done some reading and seen some of the demo clients in action.

Most of the clients in the samples allow login as a User and issue a token.

---

**Requirement**

I have multiple applications and they are, for example, MVC/SPA/Mobile, etc. I wish to allow each application to be a client and call an API.

I need a setup where applications can call a protected API without a user being logged in.  So the API is protected based on scopes.

I know I can use client_credentials flow to get `access_token` and call my API. This is fine for apps like the MVC as the secret will never be exposed.

I read that this flow is not recommended for mobile/SPA apps and to use `Authorization Code` flow, but I can't seem to get a token without it asking to log in as a User.

---

**Question**

What other flow can I use to get only access_token without logging in the user and keeping my app secure?

Or, should I just use `client_credential` flow in my mobile apps and SPA's?

Comment: Why the client credentials flow is not recommended for SPA or mobile apps? Who is claiming this?

Comment: Its in the flows section of the documentation.  I am also told that its not easy to get the best of both worlds i.e client credentials and code flow.  One for calling API without a logged in user and the other for calling it on behalf of a user.

Comment: I cant' add `identity-server4` tag because it doesn't exist and I have not enough rating to create it, but it would be nice to see